# Which types of pages in Sharepoint are modern pages and which are classic pages

Tags: sharepoint-online, modern-experience, sitepages, classic-experience

Which types of pages in SharePoint are modern pages and which are classic pages.

Is it possible to see what type of pages they are when they are created?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In SharePoint online, when you open **Site Pages** library, you can see two types of pages:

[image]

- Web part page: these are classic experience pages
- Site Page: these are modern experience pages

**Identify type of page after creation**:

1. **Using look & feel**:

   After page creation, you can easily identify the type of page by it's look & feel (see below differences).

   **Differences between classic pages and modern pages**:

   **Classic web part page**:

   [image]

   **Modern site page**:

   [image]
2. **Using content type**:

   Alternatively, you can add **Content Type** column in site pages library using view settings. It will show you the page type like:

   [image]

   Where Space type is related to [SharePoint Spaces](https://ganeshsanapblogs.wordpress.com/2020/12/03/introduction-to-sharepoint-spaces/).

Answer (score 0):

Here is how you can tell the difference between the classic and the modern pages. Just a few differences. But there are a lot more:

[image]

You can also review [the SharePoint classic and modern experiences](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/sharepoint-classic-and-modern-experiences-5725c103-505d-4a6e-9350-300d3ec7d73f#:%7E:text=Home%20page%20When%20you%20create,activity%2C%20and%20a%20Document%20library.) article from support.microsoft.com.